# In Java, how do I add spaces at the end of a string using for loop

Tags: java, string

I've been trying to add spaces at the end of my string. Earlier, I stored the number of spaces in my integer `backSpaces`
However, when I try to add the spaces using a for loop, I keep getting the spaces added in the front, or no spaces at all.
What am I doing wrong?

```
 for (int i =0; i < backSpaces; i++) {
     System.out.print(" ");
 }
 System.out.println(string);
```

Comment: Move `System.out.println(String);` to above the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to print your string before the spaces.

```
System.out.print(str);
for (int i =0; i < 5; i++){
    System.out.print(" ");
}
System.out.println();
```

I included `System.out.println();` to keep the old behavior, which is to print a new line. That way, instead of

```
string string  string   string    string
```

you'd have

```
string
 string
  string
   string
    string
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is executed in the order. Following your code the for-loop is executed then the print(String) is executed. So it's the expected behaviour that the spaces are before your string.

Just change the order to first print the string then print the spaces

```
System.out.print(myString);
for(i=0; i<myNumberOfSpaces; i++) {
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

But if you have a problem to solve this by yourself I strongly recommend you to go through tutorials about algorithmic, then through tutorials about Java.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a stringBuilder for string concatenation like so feel free to use this method it will return the string plus your number of spaces

```
private String addSpaces(String string,int spaces){
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(string);
    for (int i = 0; i < spaces; i++) {
        stringBuilder.append(" ");
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

In a program its run like so

```
System.out.println("|"+addSpaces("ThisIsMyString", 5)+"|");
```

The Output is

```
|ThisIsMyString     |
```